# How to solve system of PDE's with complicated initial and boundary conditions

Tags: graphics, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve the Cavity problem given in [Paper by Mansour et al.][1] with a physical model [![physical model][2]][2].
System of PDE and B.C are [![enter image description here][3]][3].
How can I impose boundary conditions like this?

Code

```
Clear[M, Ha, Ec, pr,  pde1, pde2, pde3]
pde1[Pr_,Da_]=u[x,y]*D[u[x,y],x]+v[x,y]*D[u[x,y],y]==-D[P[x, y], x]+Pr*(D[u[x, y],x,x]+D[u[x,y],y,y]-u[x,y]/Da);
pde2[Pr_,Da_,Ra_,Ha_]=u[x, y]*D[v[x, y],x]+v[x, y]*D[v[x, y], y]==-D[P[x, y], y]+Pr*(D[v[x,y],x,x]+D[v[x,y],y,y]-v[x,y]/Da)-Ha^2*Pr*v[x,y]+Ra*Pr*T[x,y];
pde3[Q_]=u[x,y]*D[T[x,y],x]+v[x,y]*D[D[x,y],y]==Pr*(D[T[x,y],x,x]+D[T[x,y],y, y])-Q*T[x,y];


With[{lb=2},bcs = {u[x,0]==0, v[x,0]==0,T[x, 0]==0,{u[x, lb]==0,v[x, lb]==0,T[x, lb]==0}}];

mol[n_Integer, o_: "Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines","SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n,"MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}mol[tf : False | True, sf_: Automatic] := {"MethodOfLines", "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {tf,"ScaleFactor" -> sf}}
Clear@solfuncWith[{pts = 20, lb = 2}, solfunc[Ha_, Pr_: 6.2, Da_: 2, Ra_: 1, Q_ 1, tend1_: 5] := NDSolveValue[{pde1[Pr, Da], pde2[Pr, Da, Ra, Ha], pde3[Q], bcs}, {u, v,T}, {y, 0, lb}, {x, 0, tend1},Method -> Union[mol[pts, 4], mol[True, 100]]]]

(sollst[#] = solfunc[#]) & /@ {1, 3, 6, 9}; // Quiet
```

Comment: 1. I can't find any i.c. in the picture. 2. Dirichlet b.c.s can be described with `DirichletCondition` in a straightforward manner and zero Neumann b.c. is the default setting of `FiniteElement` method; it's simple to describe the b.c.s with `Piecewise` in old-fashioned way, too. Which part are you having difficulty?

Comment: Thank you so much sir, there is no I.C conditions in problem. I can't impose the boundary conditions. it gives an error. I attached the redated paper. @xzczd

Comment: "I can't impose the boundary conditions. it gives an error. " Then please show us the failed trial so we can give targeted advice.

Comment: @Mathematicain Could you show a name of the paper instead of link to the google?

Comment: Look at the [heat transfer tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html) and the [Heat Exchanger](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Multiphysics/ModelCollection/HeatExchanger.html) that couples a fluid flow with a heat transfer equation. Generally, speaking there are mode models linked from the [PDEMoldels overview](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/PDEModelsOverview.html).

Comment: @xzczd his is the code but I can put the otherwise conditions. For simplicity, I take only fluid and skip the hybrid nanoparticles in code [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FqtgNsuXjiyejMBmthgLFM35G_SeQ-K4/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @AlexTrounev paper [link](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tsep.2017.10.014). Paper title is "**Effects of heat source and sink on entropy generation and MHD natural convection of Al2O3-Cu/water hybrid nanofluid filled with square porous cavity**"

Comment: Please add your code to your question rather than give it as external link. If it's too long to post here, it should be properly simplified to make it on-topic here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can use `FEM` as it is to solve this problem in versions 12-12.1.1

```
 Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]; 
k = 2; Pr0 = 1; Ra = 10^4; R = Ra*Pr0; a = 0; d = 1/2; b = 1/3; Da = 1; Ha = 1; Q = 1; 
reg = Rectangle[{0., 0.}, {1., 1.}]; 
{UX, VY, PK, TK} = NDSolveValue[
    {{Inactive[Div][{{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}} . Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
         Pr0*(u[x, y]/Da) + D[p[x, y], x] + u[x, y]*D[u[x, y], x] + v[x, y]*D[u[x, y], y] - 
         R*T[x, y]*Sin[a], Inactive[Div][{{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}} . Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}], 
          {x, y}] + Pr0*(v[x, y]/Da) + Ha^2*Pr0*v[x, y] + D[p[x, y], y] + u[x, y]*D[v[x, y], x] + 
         v[x, y]*D[v[x, y], y] - R*T[x, y]*Cos[a], D[u[x, y], x] + D[v[x, y], y]} == {0, 0, 0} /. 
      \[Mu] -> Pr0, u[x, y]*D[T[x, y], x] + v[x, y]*D[T[x, y], y] - (D[T[x, y], x, x] + 
        D[T[x, y], y, y]) - Q*T[x, y] == 0, DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, 
      x == 0. || y == 0. || x == 1 || y == 1], DirichletCondition[p[x, y] == 0., 
      y == 1. && x == 1.], DirichletCondition[T[x, y] == -0.5, (x == 0 || x == 1.) && 
       d - b/2 <= y <= d + b/2], DirichletCondition[T[x, y] == 0.5, 
      (y == 0 || y == 1.) && d - b/2 <= x <= d + b/2]}, {u, v, p, T}, Element[{x, y}, reg], 
    Method -> {"FiniteElement", "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1, T -> 2}, 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}];
```

Visualization of temperature and flow

```
{ContourPlot[TK[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] reg, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> 20, PlotPoints -> 25, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  PlotLabel -> T], 
 StreamDensityPlot[{UX[x, y], VY[x, y]}, {x, y} \[Element] reg, 
  StreamPoints -> Fine, StreamStyle -> LightGray, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, VectorPoints -> Fine, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLabel -> Row[{"Ra=", Ra}]]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

To calculate Nusselt number we use

```
Nu = -Evaluate[Grad[TK[x, y], {x, y}]];
```

Now we can visualize `Nu` as follows

```
{Plot[Nu[[1]] /. x -> 0, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
  Axes -> False, FrameLabel -> {"y", "Nu"}], 
 Plot[Nu[[1]] /. x -> 1, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
  Axes -> False, FrameLabel -> {"y", "Nu"}], 
 Plot[Nu[[2]] /. y -> 0, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
  Axes -> False, FrameLabel -> {"x", "Nu"}], 
 Plot[Nu[[2]] /. y -> 1, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
  Axes -> False, FrameLabel -> {"x", "Nu"}]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

To plot `Nu` over `reg` we exclude extremum points on a border

```
{ContourPlot[Nu[[1]], {x, y} \[Element] reg, PlotLegends -> Automatic,
   Contours -> 40, ColorFunction -> Hue, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Nu\), \(x\)]\)", 
  PlotRange -> {-5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 50], 
 ContourPlot[Nu[[2]], {x, y} \[Element] reg, PlotLegends -> Automatic,
   Contours -> 40, ColorFunction -> Hue, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Nu\), \(y\)]\)", 
  PlotRange -> {-5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 50]}
```

[image: Figure 3]

Code to compute flow for the case of region and temperature distribution as it shown in  Figure 4
[image: Figure 4]

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
k = 2; Pr0 = 1; Ra = 10^4; R = Ra*Pr0; a = 0; d = 1/2; b = 
 1/3; Da = 1; Ha = 1; Q = 1;
reg = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0., 0.}, {1., 1.}], 
   Rectangle[{d - b/2, 0.}, {d + b/2, b}]];
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> .001]

{UX, VY, PK, TK} = 
  NDSolveValue[{{Inactive[Div][{{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}} . 
          Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
        Pr0*(u[x, y]/Da) + D[p[x, y], x] + u[x, y]*D[u[x, y], x] + 
        v[x, y]*D[u[x, y], y] - R*T[x, y]*Sin[a], 
       Inactive[Div][{{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}} . 
          Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
        Pr0*(v[x, y]/Da) + Ha^2*Pr0*v[x, y] + D[p[x, y], y] + 
        u[x, y]*D[v[x, y], x] + v[x, y]*D[v[x, y], y] - 
        R*T[x, y]*Cos[a], D[u[x, y], x] + D[v[x, y], y]} == {0, 0, 
       0} /. \[Mu] -> Pr0, 
    u[x, y]*D[T[x, y], x] + 
      v[x, y]*D[T[x, y], y] - (D[T[x, y], x, x] + D[T[x, y], y, y]) - 
      Q*T[x, y] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, True], 
    DirichletCondition[p[x, y] == 0., y == 1. && x == 1.], 
    DirichletCondition[
     T[x, y] == -0.5, (x == 0 || x == 1.) && d - b/2 <= y <= d + b/2],
     DirichletCondition[
     T[x, y] == -0.5, (x == d - b/2 || x == d + b/2) && 0 <= y <= b], 
    DirichletCondition[
     T[x, y] == 0.5, (y == b || y == 1.) && 
      d - b/2 <= x <= d + b/2]}, {u, v, p, T}, Element[{x, y}, mesh], 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1, T -> 2}}];
```

Visualization of numerical solution
[image: Figure 5]

Comment: Thank you so much. Sir how can we fin `Nu_m` given in equation 29 to get Fig 3-5.

Comment: @Mathematicain See update to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. @Alex Trounev. Great..!

Comment: @Mathematicain You are welcome! Is this code solves your problem?

Comment: yes, this solves my problem. Ones again thank you so much.

Comment: please plot the `ContourPlot` of `Nu` in domain `{x, y} \[Element] reg`.

Comment: @Mathematicain See update to my answer.

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: @Mathematicain You are welcome!

Comment: Dear @Alex I want to export Nu_x ContourPlot with PlotLegends as an EPS file. how can I export both plot and legends as one file?

Comment: @Mathematicain We can use `nux = ContourPlot[Nu[[1]], {x, y} \[Element] reg, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> 40, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Nu\), \(x\)]\)", 
  PlotRange -> {-5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 50]` and export it as `Export["...\\nx.eps", nux]` where ... is your path.

Comment: thank you so much dear @Alex.

Comment: @Mathematicain You are welcome!

Comment: I want to simulate the same flow situation for different flow model. how can I adjust the conditions. The mode is given in this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uHiN9U1NORQ5PhpBqZWehJKxCBlxDPDo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Mathematicain Please, see update to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @Mathematicain This post it too long for the next update. If you have future questions, please, start new post.

Comment: Okay. Dear @Alex Thank you so much. I want to update this flow to open the cavity for in/outflow. Also want to Place elastic Fin in the cavity and study its behavior.